# Back In Time backup not starting via anacron because of "Can't open timestamp file for job…"

Tags: backintime, anacron

Back In Time is set up to start backups daily as soon as the external disk got connected.
This results in a udev rule which starts anacron with a config file generated by Back In Time. 
Unfortunately the backups do not run, as anacron always throws an error `anacron: Can't open timestamp file for job 1_Main_profile: Read-only file system` (seen in syslog).
The command which Back In Time generated as udev rule runs fine, if started manually (started as `root` user and as the ordinary user `jdoe`). (Also the backup runs fine when started manually via GUI.)

I would be happy to find at least out which file exactly anacron can not open, and of course why.

`udev` rule:

```
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="dd68d7f7-054b-dae0-a4a2-4315acad138a", RUN+="/bin/su - 'jdoe' -c 'test -x /usr/sbin/anacron && test -e /home/jdoe/.config/backintime/anacrontab-dd68d7f7-054b-dae0-a4a2-4315acad138a && /usr/sbin/anacron -s -t /home/jdoe/.config/backintime/anacrontab-dd68d7f7-054b-dae0-a4a2-4315acad138a -S /home/jdoe/.local/share/backintime/anacron' &"
```

`anacrontab`, modified for now to do just logging, original file (without `logger "… " ||`) did start backup fine when executed manually, but not automatically:

```
$ cat /home/jdoe/.config/backintime/anacrontab-dd68d7f7-dae0-4315-a4a2-054bacad138a
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/home/jdoe/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
DISPLAY=:0.0
1   0   1_Main_profile  /usr/bin/logger "would start backup now, but exiting, as you set in anacrontab :-)" || /usr/bin/nice -n 19 /usr/bin/ionice -c2 -n7 /usr/bin/backintime --backup-job >/dev/null 2>&1
```

files/folders (rights of '1_Main_profile' get set like this by running anacron command out of `udev` rule):

```
$ ls -ld /home/jdoe/.local/share/backintime/anacron/
drwxrwxrwx 2 jdoe jdoe 4096 Jul 18 10:41 /home/jdoe/.local/share/backintime/anacron/
$ ls -l /home/jdoe/.local/share/backintime/anacron/
insgesamt 8
-rw------- 1 jdoe jdoe 9 Jul 18 10:42 1_Main_profile
$ groups jdoe
jdoe : jdoe adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxusers
$ ls -ld /var/spool/anacron/
drwxrwxr-x 2 root adm 4096 Apr 30  2016 /var/spool/anacron/
$ ls -l /var/spool/anacron/
insgesamt 12
-rw------- 1 root root 9 Jul 18 10:20 cron.daily
-rw------- 1 root root 9 Jun 29 09:07 cron.monthly
-rw------- 1 root root 9 Jul 18 10:24 cron.weekly
```

Starting command out of udev rule manually (as `root` via `ssh`, starting it without the "`logger "…" ||` from above will start backup):

```
$ /bin/su - 'jdoe' -c 'strace /usr/sbin/anacron -s -t /home/jdoe/.config/backintime/anacrontab-dd68d7f7-054b-dae0-a4a2-4315acad138a -S /home/jdoe/.local/share/backintime/anacron &> /dev/shm/strace-anacron-backintime'
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

$ cat /dev/shm/strace-anacron-backintime
execve("/usr/sbin/anacron", ["/usr/sbin/anacron", "-s", "-t", "/home/jdoe/.config/backintime/"..., "-S", "/home/jdoe/.local/share/backin"...], [/* 26 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x562556b3c000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f75287a6000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=178056, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 178056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f752877a000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\3\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1685264, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3791264, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f75281e8000
mprotect(0x7f752837d000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f752857c000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x194000) = 0x7f752857c000
mmap(0x7f7528582000, 14752, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7528582000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7528778000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f7528778700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f752857c000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x5625560cc000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f75287a9000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f752877a000, 178056)          = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x562556b3c000
brk(0x562556b5d000)                     = 0x562556b5d000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3259968, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3259968, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7527ecc000
close(3)                                = 0
open("./", O_RDONLY)                    = 3
chdir("/home/jdoe/.local/share/backintime/anacron") = 0
umask(000)                              = 022
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
close(0)                                = 0
open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY)             = 0
close(1)                                = 0
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY)             = 1
close(2)                                = 0
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY)             = 2
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f75287789d0) = 4473
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp file in question is `/home/jdoe/.local/share/backintime/anacron/1_Main_profile`. Please make sure it is writeable. You're also  save to remove it. Anacron will write a new one next time.

But I also recommend updating to a more recent BiT version (current stable is 1.1.20). I replaced anacron dependency a while ago with pure Python code which made that schedule more reliable.

Comment: I also thought this would be the file in question. But even when making it world writable by hand, it did not work in automatic mode. And running the `su…` manually did work with the rights one can see above. (Hoping that 1.1.20 is coming soon to Stretch/Zesty/Sonya/whatever, thx for that, currently it's only 1.1.12 everywhere besides the project's repo)

Comment: Unfortunately the Debian package does not get updated on a regular basis. Just install from my PPA ppa:bit-team/stable or download the release tarball from github and build it manually with makedeb.sh script inside